# MVC 5 DropdownlistFor not validating

Tags: unobtrusive-validation, asp.net-mvc-5, dropdownlistfor

I have a dropdownlistfor and a validation field but no validation is happening.
All other fields with a validation field are validating. Anyone got an idea??

My ViewModel:

```
[Display(Name = "Organisation")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Organisation is required.")]
public Guid OrganisationId{ get; set; }
public SelectList Organisations { get; set; }
```

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
     IEnumerable<Organisation> organisations = _organisationService.FindAll();
    var model = new RegisterViewModel
    {
       Organisations = new SelectList(organisations, "Id","Name")                                  
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

My View:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.OrganisationId, Model.Organisations, "Select a value...", new { @class = "form-control choice" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OrganisationId)
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the reason is that because your using `Guid?`. The parameter type your using is `Nullable`, and so it can accepts a null value. That is why its not validating.

Try changing the the `Guid?` to `Guid`.

Comment: I have Guid. I try to make it nullable but that did not work.

Comment: Sorry, so my Viewmodel is Guid OrganisationId instead of Guid?

Comment: I have try it. Is not validating. Not if OrganisationId is nullable or non nullable. All other fields are validating just fine. Only the dropdownlistfor with default text set not validating. The value of the Default "Select a value" is set to ""